# Login details in Security context when calling from postman

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I'm trying to get the current login user from the security context but it always returns anonymoususer . i am calling the API from a rest client -POSTMAN . i want to know how i can pass the user id from the postman so that it can come in Security Context holder

````
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            // throw new BusinessException("Authorized user is not found.",
            // INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGE);
        }
        return (UserEntity) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }```
````

Comment: capture cookie (console / network tab ) and append them to your post man request ,

Comment: it depends on how your application authenticates. Show more information about it and also your security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone , 
i'm passing it in request header now and setting in the Security ContextHolder 
and i've to write an implementation of UserDetails from Spring Security to load it according to my requirements.